# ssh-add does not prevent to enter the key's password when using OpenSSH on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh, ssh-agent

I have an RSA SSH key with a passphrase on Windows 11, with OpenSSH.

I tried to add it to the agent:

```
C:\code> ssh-add -k C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa  
Enter passphrase for C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa: 
Identity added: C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa (C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa)
```

I was hoping for it to prevent me type the passphrase each time I use the key.

Obviously, it is not working:

```
C:\code> git fetch
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

The agent is running:

```
Get-Service ssh-agent

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent
```

Do you have any idea on what can be investigated?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `git` using the same version of OpenSSH as `ssh-add`/`ssh-agent`? Your `git` maybe using its own build of OpenSSH, while you maybe using `ssh-add` from Win32-OpenSSH. Those are possibly incompatible.

Comment: And even if they’re not incompatible, your Git SSH may not know about the running agent.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about that. Is there a way to ssh-add into the git agent ?

Comment: Interesting enough... If I use Git Bash instead of Power Shell...

user@MYPC MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Bureau (develop)
$ ssh-add
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell git which ssh executable it should use:

```
git config --global core.sshcommand "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"
```

Comment: If `error: cannot spawn C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or directory ` occurs, `git config --global core.sshcommand "C:/Windows/SysNative/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"` works